# Specify trait as enum variant value?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a type 'A', and various traits that define behaviours that can be done to A.

```
struct A {
   pub foo: String;
   ... etc
}

trait BigChange { 
   fn big_change(a: A) -> A
}

trait SmallChange {
   fn small_change(a: A) -> A
}

struct AConcreteBigImplementation;

impl BigChange for AConcreateBigImplementation {
   fn big_change ...
}

struct AnotherConcreteBigImplementation;

impl BigChange for AnotherConcreateBigImplementation {
   fn big_change ...
}

struct AConcreteSmallImplementation;

impl SmallChange for AConcreteSmallImplementatio {
   fn small_change ... 
}
```

I'm trying to create an enum that can refer to any behaviour, e.g.

```
// Doesn't work
enum ChangeA {
    BigChangeOperation(BigChange),
    SmallChangeOperation(SmallChange)
}
```

So that I can pass around specific operations easily, and test to see if they're BigChange or SmallChanges, e.g.:

```
let oldA = A::new( ... );
match some_change {
    BigChange(b) => let newA = b(oldA)
    SmallChange(s) => let newA = s(oldA)
}
```

I kind of understand that maybe rust wants to know a specific function at compile time, and so maybe Box'ing the values would help, but it didn't

```
// Better?
enum ChangeA {
    BigChangeOperation(Box<BigChange>),
    SmallChangeOperation(Box<SmallChange>)
}
```

Is it possible to specify a trait for an enum value like this, or what am I missing about the difference between types, traits, concrete values passed in the enum value.. ?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```rust
trait T{}

enum E {
    T(Box<dyn T>)
}
```

Comment: Huh, it does. I'm sure I'd tried that but must have messed it up somewhere. Thanks!